# Does install4j need a jre on the clients system?

Tags: install4j

I don't want to be dependent on that java is installed on the system or not
Our product already ships internally with a vm so the user doesn't have to install any java or need to have any java installed.

But this i also want for my installer of our product, there should be no need to have java there on the system to install the product, is this possible with Launch4J?
Because it is always tricky when reading the docs, you can bundle a jre, but what does that mean? Does the installer use that itself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a JRE is necessary to run the installer, but you can [bundle a JRE](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/concepts/jreBundles.html) with install4j, so no "global installation" of a JRE is requried.